# Find the number of sums that you will get A, when A=100?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Problem: Take any number $A \in \Bbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3, \dots\}$, and then take $x, y \in \Bbb{N}$, where $x \ne y$ and $x + y = A$.  Find the number of possible choices for $x$ and $y$ when $A=100$.  Order doesn't matter, e.g., $x = 80$ and $y = 20$ is the same as $x = 20$ and $y = 80$.

(Proposed by me and I solved it.) I want to know, Is there is another method that can solve this problem?  Here is my method:

From the pattern I have seen, we can say;

- When $A$ is odd, number of possibilities is $\frac{A-1}{2}$
- When $A$ is even, number of possibilities is $\frac{A-2}{2}$

And, the answer is 49 because $A = 100$ is even.

Comment: I think $x+y=y+x,$ isn't it? So if $x+y=A,$ then $y+x=A$ as well?

Comment: I edited your formatting so one can read your question, but I didn't understand a single bit... Could you please edit to make it more clear ?

Comment: If you are not comfortable using English, you might as well write the question in your own language and someone here can translate that for you. As of now, this question makes no sense.

Comment: How can we know if there is another method, when we don't know your method?

Comment: I have edited the question! Please mention if there is any difficulty while reading the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I posted the solution , how i did!

Comment: @Roby5 okey! Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @BusyAnt I have edited! See again!

Comment: @awllower No! I have edited ! see again!

Comment: Note that this question was flagged to be closed.  Rather than vote one way or another I heavily modified it to make it much more clear.  Please verify that I didn't alter the intended meaning.

Comment: @tilper You haven't altered the meaning, what I wanted to ask for ! Thanks alot!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking: Given a natural number $A$, how many pairs of distinct natural numbers $0<x<y<A$ satisfy $x+y = A$?

I believe the answer must be $\lfloor (A-1) / 2\rfloor$.

- 3 can be written as 1+2 only.
- 4 can be written as 1+3 only.
- 5 can be written as 1+4 or 2+3, etc.

In general, the rule is that $x$ can vary between $1\ldots (A-1)/2$, in which case $y=A-x$ is an integer distinct from $x$ which makes $A=x+y$. In the case that $A$ is even, we must specifically exclude the case $x=y=A/2$, so we round down.

Therefore the answer to your particular question is: when $A=100$, the number of ways is $$\lfloor(100-1)/2\rfloor=49.$$

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: $x,y $  can be  any natural number without the restriction as $0<x<y<A$.

Comment: You have did mistake, it's not $\frac{100-1}{2}$. It's $\frac{100-2}{2}$ !

Comment: @DamodarRajbhandari. I understand. Because you wanted to count each pair $\{x,y\}$ exactly once (without counting $x+y$ and $y+x$ as separate sums), I supposed without loss of generality that I will use $x$ to refer to whichever number in the pair is smaller.

Comment: @DamodarRajbhandari. I am not sure there's a mistake. The brackets $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ indicate rounding down, so when I take (100-1)/2, I get 49.5. Rounding downward gives 49 as my overall answer, which seems correct. (1+99, 2+98, 3+97, ..., 47+53, 48+52, 49+51).

Comment: Okey! Thanks for your solution sir!

Comment: Here is my method, 
From the pattern i have seen, we can say;

  When $A$ is odd, Number of sums equals $A$ is $\frac{A-1}{2}$ 
 . When $A$ is even,Number of sums equals $A$ is $\frac{A-2}{2}$.

Actually, the answer is 49 because $A$ is even.

Comment: If $x,y$ were any natural number without the restriction that $x,y<A$, there'll be infinite solutions, since $x+y=k$ is a straight-line.

Comment: @Quasar Actually, the restriction is $x,y< A$ !

Comment: @DamodarRajbhandari. I agree. Well done!  My only difference is that I combine the two cases $\text{sums}(A)=\begin{cases}\frac{A-1}{2}&A\text{ odd}\\\frac{A-2}{2}&A\text{ even}\end{cases}$ into a single expression using the "round down" operator $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$.

Comment: @Quasar The value of k should be A.

Comment: @user326210 Thanks ! This is the simple question though! Intentionally, i have another similar question but it won't follow the same pattern what we did today! Wait for that question because this time i have restricted to post another question so. And the problem is not yet solved!

Comment: @Quasar and the there won't be infinitely many solution!!

Comment: Well, if $x,y$ were unbounded, there would, right?

Comment: yes , In that case it will!

Answer (score 0):

**You've got a good intuition, but how to *prove* it ?** Here's what I'd go with, it's voluntarily very detailed :

For all $A \in \mathbb{N}$, we'll be looking for $x, y \in \left[1; A-1\right]$ so that

$$
\cases{0<x<y \\ x+y = A}
$$

And we'll try to determine how many values can $x$ take. If we know this, then we know how many combinations there are.

---

Let's start with finding the maximum value for $x$.

If $x=\frac{A+1}2$, then :

$$
x+y>x+x=A+1>A
$$

So this $x$ does not fit our case. Therefore we must have $x<\frac{A+1}2$. Since $x$ is a natural integer, this is equivalent to $x\le\frac{A+1}2-1=\frac{A-1}2$.

We have a maximum bound $M=\frac{A-1}2$.

---

Now, does it work for every integer $x$ between $1$ and $\left\lfloor M\right\rfloor$ ?

It's pretty obvious that for any integer $x \in \left[1; \left\lfloor M\right\rfloor\right]$, there exists another integer $y \in \left[\left\lfloor M\right\rfloor+1; A-1\right]$ so that $x+y=A$, and $x \ne y$

Let's see for the limit cases :

- $x=1$ : choose $y=A-1$, and $x+y=1+(A-1)=A$
- $x=2$ : choose $y=A-2$, and $x+y=2+(A-2)=A$
- ...
- $x=\left\lfloor M\right\rfloor-1$ : choose $y=\left\lceil M\right\rceil+2$, and $x+y=2M+1=(A-1)+1=A$
- $x=\left\lfloor M\right\rfloor$ : choose $y=\left\lceil M\right\rceil+1$, and $x+y=2M+1=(A-1)+1=A$

---

We have found that all $x$ between $1$ and $M$ works, and that $x$ cannot be lower than $1$ or greater than $M$. Thus we have found that there are exactly $\left\lfloor M\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{A-1}2\right\rfloor$ valid combinations.

For $A=100$, this gives :
$$
\left\lfloor M\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{100-1}2\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor49.5\right\rfloor=49
$$

Comment: I will suggest you, Try to see the pattern in that problem by addressing $x+y=A$.

Comment: Well you already did find the pattern, no need to repeat it (other answers explain it well, too). I wanted to give a mathematical _proof_, without searching for patterns but by counting how many combinations are possible for sure. You asked for another way, didn't you ?

Comment: I thought you asked how I did! Sorry for that!

Comment: Well, thanks for your concept to deal with this problem! Its great by using celing and floor concept!

Comment: If any of the provided answers were useful to you, you can upvote them to let the author know about it. In the end, please think about accepting one of them so  that we know your problem is resolved. :)

Answer (score 0):

$x+(100-x)=100$ so $x$ can go from $1$ to $49$ since   $x+(100-x)$ and $(100-x)+x$ are considered as just one case and $x\ne 100-x$

Comment: Oh yes! It can be answered from this too. Can you explain it for $ A=2003 $?

Comment: In $x+(2003-x)$ you can go till $x=1001$ because from $x=1002$ all the precedent sums are repeated by commutativity.

Comment: How can you say "you can go till $x=1001$"?

Comment: I mean predict?

Comment: My English is weak, sorry. I want to help you. I mean $x=1,2,3,,,,,,1001$ so your solution is $1001$

Comment: How can you predict the number is 1001 ? Though the reason was quite good for the number which can be predictable but it is difficult to say for large value of A.

Comment: It's okey!! Thanks for your solution.

Comment: $(\frac{A-1}{2})+(\frac{A+1}{2})=A$ When $A$ is odd. When $A$ is even you have $\frac A2=\frac A2$ to exclude because you want distinct terms in your sums.

Comment: You are welcome.